# How to share lists as lists and not as tuples between different functions?

Tags: python, list

I want to share lists between different functions like:

```
def function1():
    testlist = ['1','2','3']
    testlist.append = ('4')
    print(testlist)
    return testlist 

def function2():
    testlist = function1()
    print(testlist)
    testlist.append('6')
```

The Problem is, that as soon as I want to edit the list with for example list.append, the Error-Message 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'. Even though testlist has still the correct input in function2. Thats why I don't know why the list is correctly passed between the two functions but as a tuple and not a list. Is there a way to change the variable back to a list or to pass it as a list?

I already know that I could pass lists easier in classes. But the class would be to big for the application I want to program. I already saw this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418015/passing-a-list-between-functions-python), where the problem is discussed similar. But with these solutions I still can't edit the list in the other function.
Thanks for your help.

To clarify the problem: The code is:

The code is:
`

```
def function1():
    cfg = yaml.load(yamlfile)
    testlist = []
    list2 = []
    for x in cfg['y']
        list2.append([x, str(cfg['y'][x]['z']), cfg['g']['d'] + '\\'])
        for c in cfg['y'][x]['z']:
            if cfg['x'][y]['z'][c]['abc']:
                list2.append([str(cfg['y'][x]['z'][c]['abs'])])
    return testlist, list2
def function2():
    testlist = function1()
    list2 = function1()
    for i in range(len(list2)):
    testlist.append(list2[i][0])`
```

I hope know its a bit more clear what I want to do. Btw I just used random names in the config file.

Comment: You are assigning `testlist.append` to the value `['4']`. This will shadow the actual `append` method. Are you sure you don't just want `testlist.append(['4'])` or `testlist.append('4')` in `function1`?

Comment: Do you want to have a list inside of a list? Or just a list of numbers please OP? Please update your question to show your expected output (what you ultimately want the code to output)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was just an error here in the code. I still can't edit the list when i write testlist.append('4')

Answer (score 1):

You have a semantic error:

```
testlist.append = (['4'])
```

Is not correct:
If you want to append only '4' you should use:

```
testlist.append('4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel is right.

Be careful in your second function too.
I think you want to append '6' and not ['6'].

```
testlist.append('6')
```